# Bulk capacitance after 12 V battery input

Tags: mosfet, current, automotive, high-current, bulk-capacitor

I am working on a new project that will be mounted on my racing car. I have to make a power distribution module using e-fuse and high switch modules to control the various loads.

Exaggerating, they will flow (if all the outputs are active) maximum 90-100 A (oh yes a good current!).

On the PCB there will be two converters from 12 V to 5 V and from 12 V to 3.3 V (for the MCU). I thought of using switching since they are now at a good price. As input I thought I would use one of those screw connectors suitable for over 200 A (if I remember correctly it produces the redcube and they should be press-fit). Immediately after the input a nice power MOSFET that acts as a reverse battery protection.

Is it recommended to use bulk capacitors after the reverse battery protection? How do I calculate the capacitance I need?

Comment: Do you often connect car batteries the wrong way round? It's normally quite hard to do.

Comment: @Finbarr Well of course not. But protection doesn't hurt. Then maybe since it will be tested at the bench it is possible to be wrong even if it is difficult

Comment: @Finbarr, I imagine it's the big consequences and the big cost of getting the battery backwards that make protection worthwhile, not so much the likelihood. That assessment's true of all protection circuits: consequences vs likelihood. But I completely agree that connecting a car battery backwards in a commercial vehicle is difficult and unlikely.

Comment: *But protection doesn't hurt* Actually, it puts something in the series path between supply and load, which can be expensive and can cause significant power dissipation at very high currents which gets a bit less power to the load. So it's not a consequence-free decision.

Comment: @TonyM 
Well yes, but I insert the protection only to be able to test the pcb at the counter. And on the counter, polarity is likely to be reversed even by mistake. But my question was related to bulk capacitors. Do you think it is necessary to put them?

Comment: It depends how much resistance your protection adds to the supply path and how much effect you think that will have on the circuits being powered.

Answer (score 1):

It really comes down to how much of a voltage dip you will experience when parts of your system are powered on.  That depends in turn on:

- The internal resistance of your battery, plus the resistance of your reverse protection system.
- The maximum surge current you expect to see.

For example, motors can momentarily draw 10 times their rated current when first turned on, or maybe more.  If the voltage dips too low on start-up, then any delicate electronics may reset themselves.

Comment: As reverse battery protection I thought I was using a nice P power mosfet with a zener and a resistor. So if I reverse the polarity nothing happens downstream. The on resistance of the mosfet is 3.1mΩ so nothing to worry about in my opinion. The pcb will have 10 high switches that turn on or off loads such as: lights, heaters, fans, etc.
Obviously all these loads will not be accessed at the same time but only when needed.

Comment: 3.1mΩ at 100A gives you a drop of 0.31V and hence 31W of dissipation in your MOSFET. That's not insignificant.